# org/apache/spark/Logging issue on Hbase-Spark

Tags: apache-spark, hbase

I want to process the data on spark and insert them into HBase. I am using 
Hbase-Spark (Apache HBase) library (https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.hbase/hbase-spark/2.0.0-alpha4)

I get the following exception,

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/spark/Logging
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.spark.JavaHBaseContext.<init>(JavaHBaseContext.scala:46)
    at job.sqoop_process.HostLookupGenerator.insert(HostLookupGenerator.java:44)
    at job.sqoop_process.SparkSqoopJob.process(SparkSqoopJob.java:17)
    at job.spark.SparkExecutor$Executor.execute(SparkExecutor.java:75)
    at job.spark.SparkExecutor.main(SparkExecutor.java:37)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$$anon$4.run(ApplicationMaster.scala:721)
```

The problem is HBase-Spark-2.0.0-alpha4 version used spark Logging class which is deprecated in Spark-2.3.1.

Can anybody help me out to solve this issue.

Note: I am using Spark 2.3.1 and HBase 1.2.6.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using Spark 2.2.x and I had the same issue. I forget which of the below dependencies I managed to get it out of, but see which one is missing from your configuration and try adding it. I should work. I believe it's spark-streaming:

```
 <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
      <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
      <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
      <version>${spark.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
      <artifactId>spark-streaming_2.11</artifactId>
      <version>${spark.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
      <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
      <version>${scala.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.hbase</groupId>
      <artifactId>hbase-client</artifactId>
      <version>${hbase.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.hbase</groupId>
      <artifactId>hbase-spark</artifactId>
      <version>${hbase-spark.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.hbase</groupId>
      <artifactId>hbase-mapreduce</artifactId>
      <version>${hbase-spark.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: What is the ${hbase-spark.version} and ${hbase.version} you used. I have tried with 2.0.0-alpha4 for hbase-spark.version and 2.0.0 for hbase.version, But still it get failed. I have added spark streaming also.

Comment: hbase.version is 2.0.0. hbase-spark version for me is 3.0.0-SNAPSHOT, which I built myself from source, because for some reason hbase-spark is not yet included in the formal hbase 2.x build. However, as far as I remember, if you try it with the builds available in maven, it should work as well (like 2.0.0-alpha4)

Comment: Actually i might have been wrong above -- looks like in my case the Loging part indeed comes out of the custom-built hbase-spark version. Try building it yourself and hopefully it should work for you.

Comment: Which branch you compiled the source of hbase? I have compiled the master branch of  hbase, but the compilation got failed at HTTP module. getting the below error.

    [ERROR] Failed to execute goal net.revelc.code:warbucks-maven-plugin:1.1.0:check (run-warbucks) on project hbase-http: Problem loading classes: invalid LOC header (bad signature) -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal net.revelc.code:warbucks-maven-plugin:1.1.0:check (run-warbucks) on project hbase-http: Problem loading classes

Any thoughts?

Comment: I deliberately did not take any specific branch, because if I checked out 2.0 or whatever else, then hbase-spark wasn't there. That's why i just tried with default ant it worked.

Comment: I got it works by branching hbase master branch and taken the hbase-spark build. Thanks for your help VS_FF

Answer (score 0):

As of today, I could solve it using the version that is available at  https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.hbase.connectors.spark/hbase-spark/1.0.0

```xml
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.hbase.connectors.spark/hbase-spark -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.hbase.connectors.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>hbase-spark</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```